# Unable to expose docker container port to another container

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, networking, port

I have been trying for days to solve the following issue. I cannot make container A expose port for container B in docker compose. The two containers, however, can ping the other (so they are on the same network e.g. `ping  db` from Container B resolves the IP).

Example:

- Container A: postgres (exposes port 5432)
- Container B: django project (trys to connect to postgres on port 5432)

```
django.env

DB_NAME=freelancetracker
DB_USER=freelance
DB_PASSWORD=freelance1234
DB_HOST=postgresdb
DB_PORT=5432

postgres.env

POSTGRES_PASSWORD=freelance1234
POSTGRES_USER=freelance
POSTGRES_DB=freelancedb
```

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - postgres.env
    ports:
      - 9001:5432
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      network: host
      args:
        progress: plain
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 9101:9100
    env_file: 
      - django.env
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Container postgres:

```
    {
        "Id": "sha256:680aba37fd0f0766e7568a00daf18cfd4916c2689def0f17962a3e1508c22856",
        "RepoTags": [
            "postgres:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "postgres@sha256:901df890146ec46a5cab7a33f4ac84e81bac2fe92b2c9a14fd649502c4adf954"
        ],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2023-02-11T05:02:41.267291947Z",
        "Container": "7f186dd9993cc4c4ee68d8e17c42f9205a5b09b06131c62d79861b85ff4aec1d",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "7f186dd9993c",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5432/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.16",
                "LANG=en_US.utf8",
                "PG_MAJOR=15",
                "PG_VERSION=15.2-1.pgdg110+1",
                "PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "CMD [\"postgres\"]"
            ],
            "Image": "sha256:073c3dc2528e2f091ce4497b9f51f4a69105de3faff43bd8675b99c5c2e470a6",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/postgresql/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {},
            "StopSignal": "SIGINT"
        },
        "DockerVersion": "20.10.12",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5432/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.16",
                "LANG=en_US.utf8",
                "PG_MAJOR=15",
                "PG_VERSION=15.2-1.pgdg110+1",
                "PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "postgres"
            ],
            "Image": "sha256:073c3dc2528e2f091ce4497b9f51f4a69105de3faff43bd8675b99c5c2e470a6",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/postgresql/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null,
            "StopSignal": "SIGINT"
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 378676476,
        "VirtualSize": 378676476,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/96180dd6766f52bc67ce38513ed7747e698f217ac305a084838385a8d4ac20fb/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/60f634895fa483cfad68b8e214c8d1f9de49ebdb2745a998b416c54b41102d8c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f64d7fe2c6a4bc2ddbfbd6f16ea4f0b449198cb48a81d1f6436978a0611cef37/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ee2443b0ccb0214f316d5d2768d753745029950565ddcd1ba6f39de481359fb2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b96230816c30dacd4d657debf592ea157a85500e5d74034c247ce45341341191/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8c37275e82c0ee2a046da5028ef991b46ffecb2213e0516debc6b0de092a7810/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e0a710fea4387e9c63ab19152dce40eabd0b7f00fec7cac60c15dfa0db95b759/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0eb30ce3564590baae2091965c487d03f5a156637ae53b41835b935f96404c0f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/315fd453f617f1cd825057127cd0b1858616415e2331100239e1082d326b6498/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/acf1199b26dab7929911b87d4f72114289151abcf1476890433e29ac35f2514d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0774eeeccb8091fb778d47da5acda22bc56c2aad0be172c09c5e4b7bf9aa8081/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9a2d49d377615ac8a9c9d15bcb2473a61afeb5c799fe16fd569a16ae87fd6c94/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/547280ac6d9878acd3750a4d4bc00d4eb45851e926c6523593a3b5b92937e65e/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/547280ac6d9878acd3750a4d4bc00d4eb45851e926c6523593a3b5b92937e65e/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/547280ac6d9878acd3750a4d4bc00d4eb45851e926c6523593a3b5b92937e65e/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:4695cdfb426a05673a100e69d2fe9810d9ab2b3dd88ead97c6a3627246d83815",
                "sha256:b6ed5f2e01f9f25815836ef09685f31740700e0430a54db2f8394080567ac45f",
                "sha256:7cccddc6f072b3329408d0e8dab39507c6baac9d9462d813d13d1e31c2e46f8f",
                "sha256:dac682fc70883927473eef4261a236e2ce3178edec5abb32d3eda8986cdc3e54",
                "sha256:b33ae74a6a4df15088aef81be8199c6ae792f7c9785f0f4468c18037ead40d72",
                "sha256:273c5438a1fe742b8be8949018612e40c8365e484094b171bc8d38f01053184c",
                "sha256:ac1e4166d7d5832384b8e61ef26671a7c9bd2108f88285f5e6f0f3a2277dac08",
                "sha256:b8d11d799bc0afb68c41978505badd7c2d56e6daa91cbf87f500bcc8acb8d85f",
                "sha256:c9a28b625c28009d4374301b76788056a9d798c5db455d2fa54657a255ec72aa",
                "sha256:8eb1deb76f28073972be083fe776016ac153cac28aee947ab378869af772920c",
                "sha256:b67da121bdebcac1c05272179687d98a49f077c7faec323196bfa614e73d6d9e",
                "sha256:df0a6e5caa3cfeeb36a47f28ba29fdc1b7e60d2fa64ba8e6af48e91b1b02c958",
                "sha256:50b746e19fc3baad7fd858886a0342e595daeb9b9d2ce6917ebb339195469042"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }
]
```

Container web:

```
    {
        "Id": "sha256:b8e18a6c80fe4021b9dd0af3090a66f1d70b01bb6e3a80780128529d54072648",
        "RepoTags": [
            "freelancetracker-web:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0",
        "Created": "2023-02-22T22:41:28.139964517+01:00",
        "Container": "",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": null,
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "DockerVersion": "",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "9100/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=C.UTF-8",
                "GPG_KEY=A035C8C19219BA821ECEA86B64E628F8D684696D",
                "PYTHON_VERSION=3.11.2",
                "PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=22.3.1",
                "PYTHON_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION=65.5.1",
                "PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL=https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/1a96dc5acd0303c4700e02655aefd3bc68c78958/public/get-pip.py",
                "PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256=d1d09b0f9e745610657a528689ba3ea44a73bd19c60f4c954271b790c71c2653",
                "PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1",
                "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "gunicorn freelancetracker.wsgi --bind=0.0.0.0:9100"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/code",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.project": "freelancetracker",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "web",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "2.16.0"
            }
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 990569297,
        "VirtualSize": 990569297,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/kciu1fmzjn99p4hy8ah4dpx44/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/lmlhxa55jysrzg3h5ud9i1p4j/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/kawsbd25il6fmjrjlao4i2xmn/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/izk2v6u2sytx99nc9w68sdpxm/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/u3jqee3vo0dzok0r0ki575ozo/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/q1dbbldcujz83igd74d4pdk2c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4f9cae1eac54a29bf2404b179841d37dbf15cb3d9d30a5807237ce3de478c357/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7e1ce194f618c399861109e8a013006d32732b36c8d32ac72d186a0f41f9e49a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cb27f896f7ca332371565052ccbbb7f8706ee16020bd73e588720327103f6a9f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cd592a387a3c6770a7084c797404bf39897e8fc025058506a142f41da5df0e25/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6380d2d01b5614680f0912030898ed0b42dc8dfd2ad0eb0b29325640c4025444/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/89a40b104267d9faa73fa632d3976d66fe443b272b88132924ef005d9a8e712e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6e5beb3c2a50ec6f00dc2efbe7110c87fd15c98caa115937b8d8e5d054dd9d27/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/57a9442d168e7440e00ab55335d01eb280e721e8e98f8414e659d4e201d84713/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e43b9b338c4a70d01e8798387b4f5b525c6b282be512eca181b677bbedf4bf9e/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/o82dbggtoye3p2y8hjoollyt5/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/o82dbggtoye3p2y8hjoollyt5/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/o82dbggtoye3p2y8hjoollyt5/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:79fda049630292d45778d9b4f580ceb9952c85cb7c9baf4d83459c9b4939bab4",
                "sha256:bc73ff7e09aba434b31704124cec9d9ee7f170a26779f1002413ff066d3572b5",
                "sha256:1ba767521408aa3605a93e933ebc9aa8c9f4a8cbefc1404dc21bab4a0c6c0881",
                "sha256:b3389e626b47e1b13281c4d3f6c091d66e63f0ebe96a5572d659c9b6befe2e0b",
                "sha256:38610c0cfc18becc30c87e0af68f1c43c5cdc0ef10d920dde284df0d58fb00e1",
                "sha256:3284127ac66a9f2dc2b29d4416bd40a0aec56d6717d361cb7e399be98e7088fc",
                "sha256:aaf4891720a9cffa43d258a9e7884d20d441383e1f4a2f5b938e5f2b3ea8f087",
                "sha256:a408b1b219a7e74e18b6b7d872daa932ed7a3ebd9c2f4a9959d561416f3f7a93",
                "sha256:0b4d029be3445028329f81537abeb9b8d1bdf30b9a35ac8e3061b531996695ef",
                "sha256:1bcaaf7abf16f22d7f8c9e4d52eb914b67ab63a33d94ce9eb75e1de6e4dee2cc",
                "sha256:f3fde00a302421cf5748baab7ec2b97f71c5a71cfc9b42a836ef766fb218346d",
                "sha256:9a65fd3565b2d3566b8ac8112959ac7c27fca59652c9b52bc10af12e297a9de6",
                "sha256:06544af473a45a77410cebca29a12af8682da18150fcadc623df636c07fc8cc2",
                "sha256:4b3b831ed23d4eba23fb8f59273e1cae4e8f4b1b125588bb44f2620ab4de13bb",
                "sha256:e2750b4f328178ec9517f070b6adc0eb3f6727b41d5d9e3c086c237ee2013a30",
                "sha256:33cbcd70c6e27993bed4d0cd6c7ae3d3396de9c744eecd83cb753fc7d92d57ec"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: PS: I can reach postgres container from host on 9001 and web on 9101 but I cannot reach internet from containers

Comment: You set `DB_HOST=postgresdb`; does it need to be `DB_HOST=db` matching the Compose service name?  What is the actual error you're getting?  With modern Docker networking you don't need to "expose ports".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `DB_HOST=localhost` and `DB_PORT=9001`? You're web container is on host network and you are mapping your postgresql container 5432 port to 9001 host port.

Comment: Hi, from the web container, I am getting ```root@14fb598dacbd:/code# curl 127.0.0.1:9001
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9001: Connection refused
```